# **How to add gadget to google calendar programmatically through java?**

Tags: google-gadget

I know that I can add "Events" to google calendar through java like this

**--->client.events().insert(calendar.getId(), event).execute();**

Similarly, is there any way to add gadget to calendar?
I was unable to find javadoc information related to gadget. It would be very helpful If you let me know javadoc related to gadget.

**Note:I do not want to use GData, I want it though "Google Calendar API v3".**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this sample (it's not complete but I guess it will be enough) :

```java
Gadget g = new Gadget();
g.setLink("https://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/hellogadgets-1.2.1/hellogadgets/HelloGadgets.gadget.xml");
g.setIconLink("https://www.google.com/favicon.ico");
g.setTitle("DateTime Gadget (a classic!)");
g.setType("application/x-google-gadgets+xml");
g.setDisplay("chip");
g.setWidth(300);
g.setHeight(136);

e.setGadget(g);
```